# How do you downgrade multiple packages in arch linux?

Tags: vim, package-management, pacman

I am trying to downgrade the vim package on arch linux to an earlier version (as I need to use an earlier version of ruby which breaks it [[ref](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=191889)]).

running `downgrade vim` and selecting the version complains that I need to downgrade the `vim-runtime` package. trying to `downgrade vim-runtime` or `downgrade vim vim-runtime` complains similarly.

How do I downgrade multiple packages at once on arch linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For downgrading packages from the official repositories, your first stop should be `pacman` and your package cache in `/var/cache/pacman/pkg/`, like so:

```
pacman -U /var/cache/pacman/pkg/$pkgname-$pkgver
```

You can pass multiple packages to pacman to downgrade in this fashion.

The tools [downgrade](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/downgrade/) and [downgrader](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/downgrader/) are useful if you have cleared your cache and you need to retrieve older packages from the [Arch Rollback Machine](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_Rollback_Machine).

The Arch wiki has a typically thorough page on [downgrading packages](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Downgrading_packages).